# Hyper-Agile Submarines?

Tags: internal-consistency, underwater, ships, aircraft, shipbuilding

Building off of another question I asked about the realism of short-range combat in the future, I was thinking about making combat scenarios with small, hyper-maneuverable submarines. These submarines would need to move about like airplanes (using water dynamics over “wings” to keep motion linear at speed) and would be able to move in a linear direction while able to turn quickly by using flaps or a similar mechanic to rotate in any direction. Is essentially turning submarines into futuristic fighter planes a feasible concept? Would “flight” mechanics work differently than a traditional airplane? I would imagine buoyancy and pressure building with depth would form problems for linear travel in six degrees of motion.

Comment: ? Submarines really **can** travel in any direction they want. And they can rotate around the vertical axis, and can also dip or raise their noses to travel upwards or downwards. And they **do** have "wings" (which are called the rudder and the [diving planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_plane)). (Only five degrees of freedom, because they really really do not want to roll. Submariners greatly prefer to have their feet lower than their heads.) The biggest obstacle against "hyperagility" is that submarines are large and moving the water out of the way requires a large amount of power.

Comment: @AlexP - maybe if the submariner was mounted on gimbals they could roll.  The sub would roll around them.

Comment: @AlexP I guess that’s my question. What is stopping a submariner from having their feet above their head? And would buoyancy really not make a difference with changes in depth (to a reasonable degree)? Or would that be easy to compensate for? I’d love the submarines to be able to do loop-de-loops, etc. The subs would preferably be small (car-sized) so hopefully moving water would be less difficult.

Comment: Subs are weird -  some of the current subs could barely stand on their nose, because the they are so long the pressure differential would kill them. Also many operate in waters where their back would be out of the water if they stood on their nose..

Comment: Dunno if hyper-agile subs that'd try to dodge enemy-fire would be too compelling, primarily because most attacks against them would probably use explosives that wouldn't need to make contact.  It's also unclear what a hyper-agile sub would be used for, as opposed to simply using a torpedo.

Comment: I really don't think you understand the concept of water resistance.

Comment: @AlexP there are several factors that would discourage barrel rolls and such. The biggest being subs can only operate in a small sliver of the ocean. large combat subs have too much surface area to volume, so they cant survive great depths. Another being the equipment on board wont fair well at different angles, such as lube oil systems, reactor plant systems and fluid tanks. They can do "angles and dangles" which is limited to 35 degrees up or down, but only for a fe seconds. Plus, the sailors do not like flying around the sub much

Comment: @Sonvar Some of these wouldn’t necessarily be issues in this scenario (the single pilot would be strapped into a seat like a plane, and the subs are compact and designed for short stints). I guess by the time the craft got small enough to overcome large pressure differentials, excess of surface area, etc. there wouldn’t be room for a power source or effective structure.

Comment: @Sonvar That's partially wrong: at least one large combat sub was made to dive 1 km deep, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_submarine_K-278_Komsomolets . It suffered a bit, of course, but proved the doability of diving deeply in principle.

Comment: @GeekestGeek I am aware that there are subs that could go to 1000m deep, but a lot of gimmicks had to go into its design to allow it to do it once then required extensive maintenance in order to regain functionality. Plus, how many submarines have you lived on? I would honestly suggest, coming from experience, to take anything you learn about subs on the internet with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Sonvar As for the design, that's exactly why I said “in principle”: as with all breakthroughs, you have to do a proof of concept first and only then think of moving from the prototype to serial production. Komsomolets is extremely well known worldwide; I am sure that the message about deep diving is credible (of course, as with many measurements, up to tolerances which I don't know). Other source: http://topwar-ru.translate.goog/138-xozhdenie-za-tri-glubiny.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en

Answer (score 9):

At high speeds (starting from 77 km/h), water acts as an abrasive.  Any sub moving quickly gets polished:

> When the fastest submarine in the world came to the surface, they could not recognize it - all the paint was completely stripped off, and the welds were smoothed out.

(source: http://avtoexpert--dv-ru.translate.goog/stati/samaya-bystraya-podlodka-v-mire.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en ).  I presume that above 77 km/h, the sub hull and all protruding parts wear down quickly.

Any sub also gets noisy (100 db inside) above 65 km/h; nobody knows yet what to do with it.

As for turning upside down, it requires either

- exremely high speed, as in a barrel roll, so that the sub always thinks it's NOT upside down, or
- a true ability for every piece of equipment to work upside down for a sufficiently long period of time.

High speed has been tried (limitations were found, see above), but not extremely high speed (except for small devices such as torpedoes).

Making all the equipment being able to work upside down is, erm, expensive (again, except for simple devices such as torpedoes). Consider the kitchen, the toilets, water turning into steam in a turbine or a nuclear reactor, steam turning into water in a steam condenser, oil in a combustion engine, fuel pumps having to pump from half-empty fuel tanks, etc. Bear in mind that a sub is already a device more complicated than an orbital space station.

Comment: Welcome. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when. Nice first post. You had to mention the loos.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Alright, loos changed into toilets.

Comment: I wasn't bothered about the word so much as the mess, but fine.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Aha. So, you think that my answer would be more a mess than the original one-paragraph, unstructured post?

Comment: "Any sub moving quickly gets polished" - *except* subs that have a hydrophobic coating.

Comment: @Goodies At these loads, the type of coating probably doesn't matter: if titanium welding wears off, any coating wears off sooner or later. You could try even a titanium-tungsten alloy, and my best bet it measurably wears off at high speeds, too. Only if the sub constantly produces a hydrophobic coating (e.g.,oil) while it wears off might make a difference. Say, swimming in a bubble of gas with interspersed oil drops.

Comment: If the craft is more “short range” (I.e. designed to “fly” for a few hours or less at a time) could that overcome some design issues? For example, a kitchen would probably be unnecessary (though the toilet is a problem). Practicality of the craft aside, what is stopping a very small submarine from moving like a torpedo if the pilot is strapped in?

Comment: @MarkPrice If the sub or its hull is expendable or replaceable (how?) after a few hours, things get more doable. My best guess is that you'd need a powerful propulsion system. It needs, well, space, even if it's electrical. Then, you have to remove the noise at high speeds (and, frankly, I don't know how to do it) to protect the ears of the pilot. Finally, if the sub is swimming in a bubble in generates, it needs to effectively get rid of the heat that both the engine and the movement produces: you'd need to generate cold gas for this and/or live with the effects of heating up.

Comment: @MarkPrice Also bear in mind that noise is nothing more than vibration with low frequency. If the amplitude of the vibration gets high, it destroys first the pilot's hearing and then more or less everything else. Water is incompressible, so movement through it will generate vibration. There's no free lunch.

Answer (score 6):

### Hyper-Agile Submarines are Neither Practical nor Useful

- Reference: I'm a former Submarine Officer

From the comments, OP seems to want high speed subs that barrel roll, loop-de-loop, etc. That's going to be both **Very Technically Challenging** and **Not Actually Useful**.

### Design Challenges

The fundamental problem is power. Drag goes up with the cube (!) of velocity. So your drag force increases highly non-linearly as speed goes up.

Power is already a tough question for submarines; basically nuclear is your only choice if you want power dense, air independent propulsion. Nuclear reactors are heavy and large - a modern nuke sub is 350+ feet long, and 30+ feet in diameter, and around half of that space is dedicated to propulsion.

So you'd have to hand wave a truly spectacular power source to get anything like the performance OP desires.

### Tactical Challenges

Assuming you did find that power source, you run into the issue of stealth. The faster you go the more noise you make. That noise makes it easier to find you, and harder for you to find other subs (!) because your self noise blinds your own sensors.

A sub trundling along at 5 knots will kill a sub blazing past it at 50 knots, because the slow boat will be invisible on sonar, while the fast boat is highly detectable.

### Combat Challenges

Assuming that the fast boat actually hears the incoming torpedo, the ability to "dodge" is not actually that useful. The explosion from a torpedo creates an over-pressure wave that slams into the hull, damaging it - physical torpedo-to-hull contact is not required.

**I don't see hyper-agile submarines as a thing.**

Answer (score 5):

**Supercavitating sub.**

[image: supercavitating torpedo]

https://navalpost.com/a-gamechanger-weapon-supercavitating-torpedo/

https://www.19fortyfive.com/2021/09/the-supercavitating-torpedo-the-one-weapon-the-u-s-navy-cant-match/

> Supercavitating torpedos on the other hand travel extremely
> fast—hundreds of kilometers an hour. Torpedos of all types are slowed
> down by drag caused by friction with water. One way to overcome this
> drag is with bubbles.
>
> Supercavitating torpedos travel through the water in a large bubble
> that encapsulates most or all of the torpedo. Compressed gas stored
> inside the torpedo is ejected out of the nose, and the torpedo
> “glides” through the water inside the bubble, remaining relatively
> dry.
>
> Control surfaces, generally fins, pierce the bubble and maintain
> contact with the water, allowing the torpedo to steer.

Instead of just a torpedo, your whole sub is supercavitating.  It is driven by a fusion engine which provides more than ample power.  The gas used to envelop the submarine is steam.  Steam is also the propulsive force and is blasted out the rear of the submarine like a rocket engine.   Like the supercavitating torpedo, the sub flies through the water at great speed, freed of the draggy draggedness by its bubble suit.

It is much like flying a jet.  In the dark, underwater.

Comment: A jet whose skin is boiling, I can't help but notice. This might be useful for a "turbo" button but if it was your normal method of travel, I'd be worried about your thermal load.

Comment: @Cadence - Load, schmoad!  I will dump my load in the cool coolth of the swirling waters.   As one does.

Comment: But the water is on the other side of the steam. Unless your steering vanes are also cooling fins. I don't see a single way that could possibly go wrong.

Comment: It would also be noisy as hell which, underwater, is the equivalent of having a "Torpedo me!" sign taped to their back.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Only if the torpedo can catch you.  And if the crew of the vessel with torpedoes have the reflexes to launch in time, which is why navies are so worried about supercavitating torpedoes which are on top of you before you can do anything about it.

Comment: If i could i'd give you a second +1 just for "draggy draggedness" :-)

Comment: @Graham, aircraft dropped munitions. They're a thing. Plus your supercavitating sub is going to be so damn loud it will be trivial to hear it coming long before it gets close enough to be a threat.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Why are you assuming it runs at full speed all the time? No other submarine, in the history of submarines as a weapon, has ever done that whilst approaching a target.  As with any other sub, they'd get close enough that their targets can't react in time.  Vastly increased speed is a game-changer in enabling submarine attacks to be more like strafing/bombing runs, instead of simply standing off and firing torpedoes.  You're unlikely to get your aircraft off the deck in time, and you're even less likely to have a carrier to land your aircraft on afterwards.

Comment: @Graham, if they would attack the same way as any other sub, why would they do something like a "strafing run" and not use normal torps (or even supercavitating ones) at standoff distances like anyone else? Current torpedos can be fired 50 km or more away from the target, are almost impossible to detect unless they go active, and the first time you know they're there is when something blows up. And while they're on their way, the sub can quietly Be Somewhere Else.

Comment: @Graham, I see this kind of thing quite a lot when someone postulates some kind of radical new technology. They tend to overlook the fact that, in evaluating the effectiveness of said technology, the enemy also gets a vote. In other words, why would you assume that if said tech was possible, no one has bothered thinking about ways to counteract it?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR: Definitely physically and technologically viable, but tactically dubious.**

**A fighter jet submarine would probably be outrun and outdived by any proper ships that are bigger than it, and it would probably be outmanoeuvred and shot down by any torpedoes that are smaller than it. There's no technical barrier to *building* a hyper-agile combat submarine— Fluid dynamics follow the same basic laws underwater and above water— But the different environment underwater means that it likely just won't make tactical sense.**

---

This is a thing that already exists:

[image: https://thumbs.gfycat.com/HealthyMilkyLeveret-size_restricted.gif]

[Via GfyCat.](https://gfycat.com/healthymilkyleveret-submarine-dolphin-beahero-session-action)

A company called SeaBreacher makes them. Although, as their intended application is for recreation and entertainment, the real-world examples seem to have positive buoyancy so they'll automatically return to the surface unless you're actively pushing them down— But the behaviour should be largely similar with neutral buoyancy that is capable of diving much deeper.

That said, I'd want to think hard about the kinematics and energetics of what you're proposing.

Modern combat aircraft are shaped by a variety of evolutionary races:

- Speed of missiles versus speed of aircraft. An example of aircraft winning would be the SR-71, which could simply accelerate when shot at, and outrun any missiles fired at it. Examples of aircraft losing would be the XB-70 and B-1A, which could fly very nearly as fast as the  SR-71 but ended up getting shelved because they were expected be shot down with increasingly advanced missile technology.
- Altitude reach of different types of aircraft versus altitude reach of interceptors, missiles, and radar. Related to above, aircraft like the U-2 have tried to stay out of reach of enemy air forces by simply flying higher than interceptors and missiles could reach. When that failed, many bombers and fighters instead switched to flying low enough to use the terrain to hide from radar, prompting a drastic rethink in the design space.
- Manoeuvrability of aircraft versus manoeuvrability of missiles/countermeasures. When aircraft are more manoeuvrable than missiles, you tend to get a lot of close-up dogfights with their internal cannons and infrared/heat-seeking short-range missiles. When missiles are more manoeuvrable than aircraft, a lot more emphasis is placed on having powerful radars and high speed at the cost of agility, as then whoever shoots first can be expected to win. In the early jet age, a lot of US fighter jets were built on the expectation that air-to-air missiles would make dogfighting a thing of the past. Their poor performance against slower but more manoeuvrable opposing MiGs meant that the following decades of US fighter jets (think F-15, F-16) ended up putting a lot more emphasis on manoeuvrability again.
- Buoyancy versus wings. For some time, lighter-than-air airships, not fighter and bomber planes, were the most prominent form of both military and civilian aviation. Their huge disadvantage is that much of their mass and volume always has to be spent just on keeping themselves in the air, while advances in engine technology and aerodynamics allow every generation of airplanes to carry a greater fractional mass of usable payload.
- Sensor range versus stealth.
- Ability to generate kinetic energy versus ability to retain it (thrust versus drag, I guess).

Underwater, a lot of these things are completely different. There's both a lot more more inertia and a lot more viscosity, so the Reynolds number is gonna be different. The fluid's incompressible. You'll get more inertial/viscous/skin drag, but the speed of sound is also much, much higher, so the Mach number is going to be lower and you'll get less wave drag. Radar and optical light won't go far, while sonar doesn't travel at the speed of light and can be confused by your own engines, so you're comparatively blind. Active power isn't needed: Jets *have* to keep moving, because otherwise they'll fall out of the sky, but you a submarine can silently float in one place basically forever. Buoyancy isn't a *cost* like it is in airships; buoyancy is basically a *given*, so the main downside of having a massive ship instead of smaller craft is also negated.

I don't want think too much about this, but altogether, I'm not sure there will be any place for fighter jet-style submarines. Shorter vision, high drag, free buoyancy— All these environmental factors seem to work against the conditions that have led to the evolution of modern combat aircraft above the surface. A big, heavy real-world-style submarine would likely be able to travel further, hide deeper, run faster, stick around longer, and carry more payload than smaller, hyper-agile craft, while a small, automated torpedo or drone would likely be able to outmanoeuvre it without having to carry a pilot or fuel for the return trip. Any role it could fill would be better filled by either something much larger or something much smaller.

You'll notice that despite hyper-agile submersible watercraft already existing in our world, no militaries are trying to use them in any role resembling that of fighter aircraft.

---

If you still want fighter jet-style submarines, I recommend making them deploy from an aircraft carrier-style mothership sub that's big enough to take advantage of the conditions I mentioned above, and coming up with some sort of excuse for either why automated torpedoes aren't viable (E.G. no microprocessors, easily hacked), or why automated torpedoes are actually fighter jets and have the same stakes as fighter jets (E.G. remotely driven, pilot executed on loss).

Comment: "the behaviour should be largely similar with neutral buoyancy that is capable of diving much deeper" except probably nowhere near as acrobatic

Comment: @theonlygusti And why would that be? Dolphins and other entirely submersed active swimmers can be plenty acrobatic, and wave drag is apparently the biggest source of resistance for surface ships. (IRL subs can often go faster underwater than on the surface because of that.)

Comment: Upvoted ! *Spectacular* toy.. reminding me of dolphins, or shark !

Comment: The only reason I’d need submarines instead of planes is if this type of combat would be more viable that way. This has more than adequately explained why they probably wouldn’t. I’d also imagine as pressure increases, agility would decrease pretty heavily, and ideally this would be nowhere near the surface.

Comment: @MarkPrice Depth/pressure shouldn't have much *direct* effect on agility, as water's incompressible, so viscosity and density shouldn't change too much with pressure. *Indirectly*: Higher pressure means needing a stronger and heavier hull, which will in turn decrease agility. That said, agility will be pretty poor at *any* depth compared to aircraft— Water's ~1000X denser than air, so it will be around 1000X harder to move around.

Comment: Probably a much more broad and in depth question, but could the density issue be overcome if the subs aren’t in water? Just armchair fluid dynamics makes me think that liquid methane (less dense, not polar) would allow more maneuverability, but changing the medium most likely raises more questions than it answers.

Comment: @WillChen bc the seabreacher's speed is 60 mph but only 25 mph as soon as it submerges (only 5ft). All its acrobatic stunts come from flipping through the air, I haven't found a video of it changing directions fast or flipping underwater.

Comment: @MarkPrice Maybe? It's still gonna be incompressible, and way denser than air, though. Also, keep in mind that most non-water liquids will eventually freeze into a solid chunk if put under enough pressure.

Answer (score 3):

**Fish shaped submarines**

Yeah submarines have a hopeless design. Under water, better use a robotic construct, shaped like a fish. It can minimize energy consumption by moving in resonance, like fish do.

There are also rigid constructs in design, shaped like a fish,

[image]

*"A whale shark/manta ray-shaped mothership would be built from super-strong alloys and acrylics, with surfaces which can morph in shape. With hybrid algae-electric cruising power and propulsion technologies including tunnel drives which work similarly to a Dyson bladeless fan, the submarine could travel at unprecedented speeds of up to 150 knots."*

https://www.maritime-executive.com/article/royal-navy-considers-fish-shaped-submarines

Comment: What's "moving in resonance"?

Comment: @theonlygusti before I found that link, I considered having a submarine with an actual fish body and tail. Fish move very effectively on low energy, because they move by wagging their tail in the water, "resonating" themselves forward. Compare human walk, that is also a form of resonance and very effective.

Comment: I just found this article about resonant motion in fish: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsif.2013.1073 Looks like fish have optimal frequency of undulation considering the resonant frequency of their bodies and "the frequency of maximum spatial amplification of unstable wake" in the fluid around them